# How can I load PNGs into a PictureControl?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, png, doublebuffered

What can I use to load PNGs into a Picture Control, in a way that uses double-buffering?

I've been using [this code](http://read.pudn.com/downloads64/sourcecode/others/224347/%E4%BB%8ECWnd%E6%B4%BE%E7%94%9F%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E7%B1%BB/CustomControl/BitmapViewer.cpp__.htm), which handles the double-buffering for BMPs, as to avoid the flicker of constant repainting. Now I need to switch to PNGs to reduce the app size.

I found [CxImage](https://workspaces.codeproject.com/user-10819819/cximage), but the whole library is too big and it would defeat the purpose of switching to PNGs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You already handle the painting so you might as well use [`<GdiPlus.h>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  It can load and paint PNGs and is included with any Windows version.  JPEG as well, smaller yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stay with your BMP code. To bring it to the screen you need the bitmap (or use GDI+ as mentioned in a comment).

Load the PNG file with CImage. Use CIamge::Detach and you have your PNG as a bitmap. Than use your current code.

Loading the PNG into a CImage can be done from disk or from a memory buffer (resource) with a stream. In both cases use CImage::Load.

Afaik there is a simple CPngImage class in the MFC that derives from CBitmap, that provides all functions you need.